# Convert String to comma separated single quote values in vertica database

Tags: sql, vertica

I have data like this `"1,2,3,4"` (String). I need to convert this to `('1','2','3','4')`, so that i can use like `select * from table where ids in ('1','2','3','4')`.

Is there any in built function in vertica to convert string to comma separated array..?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try the text index functionality. Otherwise, convert the string to a table and perform a join. Your method is not efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below method ( on vertia 7.1.X) :

```
select * from mytable  where id  in (select words  from (
select TxtIndex.StringTokenizerDelim('1,2,3,4,5,19 ',',') over () from dual 
) as aa )
```